# Book recommendation for studying biology for neuroscience

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, book-recommendation

I will be starting a double degree in neuroscience and mathematics very soon, and I realised that an understanding of human biology can really help me out, and so I'm looking for an introductory level biology textbook that also covers things in **great detail**. I have no background in biology whatsoever.

Also, am I supposed to learn about the biology of plants for example before diving into human biology or can I just get started with human biology straightway.

By the way, I'm not looking for a biology textbook that has a mathematical approach, just the traditional approach can suffice.

Comment: Book recommendations are off topic for the biology stack exchange

Comment: Will you be an undergraduate student?

Comment: @BryanKrause yes

Comment: Presumably with those majors you will take a general biology course your first year, and subsequent courses in genetics, cell biology, and physiology most likely your second year. Each will come with an a textbook no doubt.

Comment: Yeah well, from my experience with mathematics for example, the textbooks recommended in the course outline were not really great, they were very surfaced level and focused more on application rather than theory and rigour. The textbooks I found most useful were actually recommended to me by the maths overflow community. So I'd naturally assume that it'll be the same case for neuroscience, hence the reason I posted this question, plus I'd also like to start studying these subjects early, even though i'll be introduced to the fundamentals once I commence my degree. @BryanKrause

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are looking for a general biology (as you've indicated in your question body) or neuroscience (as you've indicated in your previous comment) textbook. The two most popular neuroscience textbooks are arguably Kandel's "Principles of Neural Science" and Squire's "Fundamental Neuroscience". Both devote a few introductory chapters discussing topics that could be described as general biology.

Comment: I agree with @vkehayas, you could add Purves to the list as well. I just don't think there is going to be a good answer for what you are looking for though: a introductory textbook that covers things in great detail is kind of an oxymoron, and it's going to be entirely a matter of opinion to resolve the conflict between the two. There is far more to understand in biology than there is in the foundations of mathematics.

Comment: Ok, Fine. I'll join. Kandel is excellent. I took his class back in the day. If you had one nueroscience textbook, I would definitely recommend that over Purves. Sorry @BryanKrause . You'll want Albert's MBoC as well.

Comment: I never said Purves > Kandel just adding it to the list :) @DanHall I haven't personally used Kandel ever but have certainly heard good things.